# In Keras what is the difference between weight_regularizer and activity_ regularizer

Tags: keras, regularized

I understand regularization normally adds k*w^2 to the loss to penalize large weights. But in Keras there are two regularizer parameters - weight_regularizer and activity_ regularizer. What is the difference?

Comment: I don't find weight regularizer in specifications, but there is kernel regularizer. I assume that it is same since kernels are some kind of weights. Am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that `activity_regularizer` is applied to the output from an intermediate layer, it penalizes large layer output.